# Nested groupingBy for maps with an inner ImmutableList?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have something along these lines:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClass>>> someMap = 
    .... (streams and filtering, etc.) 
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
       x -> getSomeComputedAttribute(x),
       Collectors.groupingBy(x -> getSomeOtherComputedAttribute(x));
```

This, so far, is working fine - I'm getting the right values, but the problem is I need to turn the List into an ImmutableList. What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already [pointed out by Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229560/2711488), the simplest solution is to collect into a `List` using the built-in collector and transfer the collected elements into an `ImmutableList` in a post-processing step:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClass>>> someMap = 
    /* your stream operation */
    .collect(groupingBy(x -> getSomeComputedAttribute(x),
        groupingBy(x -> getSomeOtherComputedAttribute(x),
                   collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf))));
```

This, of course, has the slight performance drawback of copying the entire list contents.

A natural solution would be a builder based collector, e.g.

```
public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toImmutableList() {
    return Collector.of(
        ImmutableList::<T>builder,
        ImmutableList.Builder::add,
        (b1,b2) -> b1.addAll(b2.build()),
        ImmutableList.Builder::build);
}
```

and use it like

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClass>>> someMap = 
    /* your stream operation */
    .collect(groupingBy(x -> getSomeComputedAttribute(x),
        groupingBy(x -> getSomeOtherComputedAttribute(x), toImmutableList())));
```

but surprisingly, this won’t gain any performance improvement, as this will still copy the builder’s contents when building the `ImmutableList` in almost all cases, as it only will share its internal array, if the number of collected elements exactly matches the array’s capacity.

Still, it may get an advantage of updated Guava libraries in the future…

---

Alternatively, you may reconsider whether it really has to be a Guava implementation of an immutable list. You may get an immutable list without a copying step via:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClass>>> someMap = 
    /* your stream operation */
    .collect(groupingBy(x -> getSomeComputedAttribute(x),
        groupingBy(x -> getSomeOtherComputedAttribute(x),
                   collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList))));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're restricted to a pre-Java 8 Guava -- one is coming soon -- then probably the simplest workaround (and not a bad one, honestly) is `collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf)`.

Comment: You'd use that as the second argument to groupingBy, after the key function.  And there is no currently released Guava with Java 8 features, though as I said there will be soon.